# Easy way to share a changing email group listing?

Tags: email, contacts, address-book

I have a group of friends and acquaintances that participate in a periodic activity during lunch hours at work (for example getting together to play cards, or a game of soccer, etc). The problem is that most people work in different places, so organization is best done via email as some members cannot access certain web sites (e.g. Facebook - so Facebook Groups are out).

When someone is added or removed it takes a while for the "list" to be updated all across the board presenting issues with people being left out, or continuing to get unwanted emails. Adding to the difficulty is the fact that many of the members are not overly technically savvy, so creating complex applications or infrastructure is out of the question as well.

Is there an easy way to store lists of email addresses that could be shared amongst peers? Something like delicious.com comes to mind for me but searching for "sharing email groups" brings up some pretty terrible results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Posterous](http://posterous.com), which looks like a very simple interface for creating a website, has Facebook integration, and can double as email lists now:

> http://blog.posterous.com/posterous-group-blogs-are-now-email-lists-too

Comment: I'm convinced, this is excellent. Hopefully I can convince the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use something like [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/s/mailman/index.html)? I know a couple of mailing lists using it. However, this would need at least some free webhosting. Other possibility could be Google Groups, but it needs Gmail account (I think).

Comment: I use a google group to manage my version of the list, but most others use work email addresses, other accounts, etc. Not good for syncing as far as I can tell.

Comment: and what about Doodle? http://doodle.com/ But I am not sure whether it can be used in a group, I used it only to plan some meetings etc., but I do not have registration yet, so I have limited experience.